# Is it safe to invoke callbacks from NAPI async worker thread?

Tags: node.js

In my nodejs NAPI C++ addon, I need to maintain a long-running process in a background thread. Periodically, the process needs to let the front-end javascript know the current status.

I am implementing a `Napi::AsyncWorker` based class. The idea is that my process will run within the `Execute` method and periodically invoke the javascript callback that has been provided to the instance.

Is it safe to invoke callback methods from the `Execute` method? Is there any other way? Regards.

Answer (score -1):

You would go better with AsyncWorkerProgress

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: the question was : **Is it safe to invoke callback methods from the Execute method? Is there any other way? bold**. _AsyncWorkerProgress_ is definitely a better way to invoke callbacks